# PyCharm running scripts in Python Console

Tags: pycharm

I don't know if I accidentally pressed a hotkey or what, but suddenly my PyCharm interpreter is automatically launching my code in the "Python Console" instead of the run window when I select "Run".  When I go to View > Tool Windows, "Run (Alt + 4)" is greyed out.  How do I switch back to running scripts in the Run window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Run/Debug Configurations` (you can find it in the menu bar in the drop down menu) and have a look if the check-mark `Run with Python console` is set. If so, deactivate it and try again.